# extract the exact word from a string in powershell

Tags: powershell, substring, extract

I have a string in a file like this:

```
<a href="DevOpsPortal-20160630_142543.zip">DevOpsPortal-20160630_142543.zip</a>            30-Jun-2016 14:26  3.71 MB
```

from which i want the word `evOpsPortal-20160630_142543.zip` alone as output. I tried using the command

```
Get-Content .\file.txt | Select-String "[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+.zip"
```

but what it returned was "DevOpsPortal-01-07-2016-15-18-56.zip        05-Jul-2016 11:16  3.60".

How could i get only the expected word from this line ?

Answer (score 0):

Grab [the `Matches` property of the resulting object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.matches(v=vs.85).aspx), and then grab the `Value` property from that (here using a simpler regex pattern):

```
$myString = Get-Content .\file.txt |Select-String "\w+-\d+_\d+\.zip" |ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

Comment: Sorry Mathias , i made a mistake in my question the actual string i am parsing is "<a href="DevOpsPortal-13-07-2016-12-51-40.zip.md5">DevOpsPortal-13-07-2016-12-51-40.zip.md5</a>" from which i want only DevOpsPortal-13-07-2016-12-51-40.zip. Can you please help me

Comment: @Rajagopalan Answer is still the same :) Have you tried it?

Comment: i tried replacing the "_" with "-" but now it returns only 12-51-40‌​.zip

Comment: Change pattern to `\w+-(?:\d+-)+\d+\.zip`

Comment: Thanks Mathias. It  is working fine; can you explain me what is the difference in two patterns, since i am new to powershell.

Comment: These are regex patterns, not specific to powershell. I'll update the answer later